# Printing out a list using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

So I have this assignment that is asking to print every other value, print one skip one, but I'm having trouble doing it, all I did was make it print the all of the iterator, need help.

```
void print_even(const list<short>& data)
{
    if (data.empty())
    {
        cout << "<>";
    }
    else
    {
        list<short>::const_iterator iter = data.cbegin();
        cout << "<" << *iter;
        ++iter;


        while (iter != data.end())
        {
            cout << ", " << *iter;
            ++iter;

        }
        cout << ">";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the status with an `if`:

```
int index = 0;
while (iter != data.end())
{
    if (index++ % 2) {
        cout << ", " << *iter;
    }
    ++iter;

}
```

This will print the odd positions. If you need to print the pair positions, then instead of `index++ % 2` you need `(!(index++ % 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you could use the %2 approach, you don't *need* to, there are other options.

One option is to increment twice for each output.
If there's any chance that the loop is over an odd number of elements you'd need make sure the loop still terminates correctly and it doesn't just skip over the end. There's lots of ways of doing that too, one way would be checking for end twice:-

```
    while (iter != data.end())
    {            
        ++iter;  // increment without output since first element is handled outside loop

        if(iter == data.end()) // 2 checks due to 2 increments per loop
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << ", " << *iter;
        ++iter;
    }
```

Or you could have a bool that controls whether you output:-

```
  bool shouldOutput = false; // starts false as first item already output
  while (iter != data.end())
  {
      if(shouldOutput)
      {
          cout << ", " << *iter;
      }
      shouldOutput = !shouldOutput;
      ++iter;
  }
```

I'm not saying that these are much better than the %2 approach, just pointing out some other approaches.